# Why does DBI implicitly change integers to strings?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have a MySQL table with following structure.

```
alid       bigint(20),
ndip       varchar(20),
ndregion   varchar(20),
occ_num    int(3),
Delta_Flag int(1)
```

After selecting data from the table, I am getting all the data quoted and as a string value.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
use Database;

my $pwd = $FindBin::Bin;

my $db  = Database->new( 'mysql', "$pwd/config.ini" );
my $db1 = Database->new( 'mysql', "$pwd/config2.ini" );

my @tables = qw( AutoTT_AlarmStatus_Major1 );

for my $table ( @tables ) {

    my $query_select = "SELECT alid, ndip, ndregion, occ_num, Delta_Flag FROM $table LIMIT 1";
    my $result = $db->db_get_results( $query_select );

    print Dumper( $result );

    for my $item ( @{$result} ) {

        # Here I want to prepare, bind and insert this data
        # into other table with same structure
    }
}
```

#### Database.pm

```perl
sub db_get_results {
    my $self = shift;
    my $qry  = shift;

    my $sth  = $self->{dbh}->prepare( $qry );
    $sth->execute();

    my @return = ();
    while ( my @line = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
        push @return, \@line;
    }

    return \@return;
}
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1788353',
            '10.34.38.12',
            'North Central',
            '1',
            '1'
          ]
        ];
```

Why is `DBI` implicitly converting all integers to strings?

Comment: Do you realise that it doesn't make any difference in Perl?

Comment: Yes, not in Perl but if I want to insert this data into other table with same structure then it is a problem. I need to do the conversion back explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean by "not in Perl"? You can use the data as it is to create a new record using Perl. If you hadn't used `Data::Dumper` to view the data then you would have found it very difficult to discover whether you had strings or integers. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Borodin, while it's true that generally the string vs number issue doesn't matter in Perl, it's also true that there are times when it does. Serializing to JSON is a common example.

Comment: What version of DBD::mysql are you using?

Comment: @Borodin I meant yes, indeed it doesn't matter in Perl. But, I thought it would matter in `MySQL`. Anyway, as you told I tried to insert using `bind variables` and It is working as expected. Strange, means `DBI` again implictly converted it into expected data-types for `MySQL`.

Comment: @TimBunce I am using DBI version `1.631`.

Comment: @TimBunce: I'm unsure what point you're making there. It takes some arcane code to differentiate between the possible types of value that may be stored in a Perl scalar variable. All the JSON modules that I have used encode all scalar values as strings unless they are references to an array or to a hash, but I am no oracle so please correct me. Did you have something more profound in mind? The only core Perl operator whose result depends on the IOK and POK flags are the bitwise logical operators, and in this context I didn't see any reason to discuss them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @choroba notes in his answer, it's not the DBI that's doing anything with the data. It's just passing through what the driver module (DBD::mysql in your case) returned.

In the [General Interface Rules & Caveats](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#General-Interface-Rules-Caveats) section of the DBI docs it says:

> Most data is returned to the Perl script as strings. (Null values are returned as undef.) This allows arbitrary precision numeric data to be handled without loss of accuracy. Beware that Perl may not preserve the same accuracy when the string is used as a number.

I wrote that back in the days before it was common to configure perl to support 64-bit integers, and long-double floating point types were unusual. These days I recommend that drivers return values in the most 'natural' Perl type that doesn't risk data loss.

For some drivers that can be tricky to implement, especially those that support returning multiple result sets, with different numbers of columns, from a single handle, as DBD::mysql does.

I skimmed the [DBD::mysql docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql) but didn't see any mention of this topic, so I looked at [the relevant code](https://metacpan.org/source/MICHIELB/DBD-mysql-4.040/dbdimp.c#L4082-4099) where I can see that the current DBD::mysql *is* returning numbers as numbers. There's also lots of [references to recent changes in this area in the Change log](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/DBD-mysql#L2-48).

Perhaps you're using an old version of DBD::mysql and should upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I will try with different version. It is also noticeable that during *insertion* to `MySQL` the data is again converted into expected data type from strings through DBI.

Answer (score 3):

That's how the DBD driver for MySQL works. Other databases might behave differently. For example, in SQLite, numbers remain numeric:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $dbh = 'DBI'->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:', q(), q());
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE t (id INT, val VARCHAR(10))');

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO t VALUES (?, ?)');
$insert->execute(@$_) for [ 1, 'foo' ], [ 2, 'bar' ];

my $query = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, val FROM t');
$query->execute;
while (my $row = $query->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    print Dumper($row);
}

__END__
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          'foo'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          'bar'
        ];
```

Comment: Some words would help a lot. You seem to be demonstrating that SQLite is *different*, but that doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: @Borodin: Added some words.

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing DBI does in general. As it already was pointed out many database-drivers (DBD::xy) of the DBI system convert numbers to strings. AFAIK its not possible to avoid that.

What you can do is ask the statement handle for corresponding native type or (easier in your case) wether the column of your resultset is numeric in the mysql-DB or not.  Here is an example

Given this basic database:

```
mysql> create table test (id INT,text VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'lalala');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

you can lookup wether the column is numeric or not by using the driver-specific field 'mysql_is_num':

> Reference to an array of boolean values; TRUE indicates, that the respective column contains numeric values.
>   (from [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql))

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,'user','pass') or die "$!";
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute(1);

my $num_fields = $sth->{'NUM_OF_FIELDS'};
my $num_mask = $sth->{'mysql_is_num'};

my $result;
my $cnt = 0;
while (my $line = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref){
    for (my $i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++){
        if ($num_mask->[$i]){
            $line->[$i] + 0;
        }
        $result->[$cnt] = $line;
    }
    $cnt++;    
}

print Dumper($result);
```

I hope this helps. As it was written in a hurry, please excuse the style. Of course i'm open to any suggestions.